# c++ vector bubble sort

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, bubble-sort

I use g++ -std=c++11 Sort.cpp to compile my file.

My problem is the bubble sort don't sort.

Maybe I'm passing the vector by value but I don't know is closely my firt time trying work with c++ and I chose use vector library.

My code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void bubbleSort(vector<int> a);

void printVector(vector<int> a);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    vector<int> a{3,2,6,1};
    printVector(a);

    bubbleSort(a);
    printVector(a);
}

void bubbleSort(vector<int> a)
{
    bool swapp = true;
    while(swapp)
    {
        swapp = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.size()-1; i++)
        {
            if (a[i]>a[i+1] )
            {
                a[i] += a[i+1];
                a[i+1] = a[i] - a[i+1];
                a[i] -=a[i+1];
                swapp = true;
            }
        }
    }
}

void printVector(vector<int> a)
{
    for (int i=0;  i <a.size();  i++)
    {
        cout<<a[i]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

In the main I declare a vector type of int's and make the list {3,2,6,1}

After that e call the function `printVector` wich pretends print all numbers of vector on console and call `bubbleSort` function and finally print again.

Comment: Pass the vector by reference: `void bubbleSort(vector<int>& a)`

Comment: Aside: clever swapping tricks are more likely to hurt than help these days.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**You need to pass by reference**; by making a copy, you sort a temporary copy, and then that's it; it disappears and the original is still unsorted, because, once again, **you sorted only a temporary copy of the entire vector.**

So change `vector<int> a` to `vector<int>& a`.

Here's the code, fixed:

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2f118555f585ccd5

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void bubbleSort(vector<int>& a);

void printVector(vector<int> a);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
 vector<int> a {3,2,6,1};

 printVector(a);

 bubbleSort(a);

 printVector(a);



}

void bubbleSort(vector<int>& a)
{
      bool swapp = true;
      while(swapp){
        swapp = false;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < a.size()-1; i++) {
            if (a[i]>a[i+1] ){
                a[i] += a[i+1];
                a[i+1] = a[i] - a[i+1];
                a[i] -=a[i+1];
                swapp = true;
            }
        }
    }
}

void printVector(vector<int> a){
    for (size_t i=0;  i <a.size();  i++) {
        cout<<a[i]<<" ";

    }
  cout<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are passing the vectors as values to your functions, meaning that you are sorting a copy, not the original vector, and then printing a copy of the original vector.

Change the parameter to `vector<int> &a` in the `bubbleSort` function, and to `vector<int> const &a` in the `printVector` function (as you don't need to change the vector content from here).

By the way, your code may be affected by undefined behavior caused by signer integer overflow.
You should use another method to swap your elements, `std::swap` for example:

```
std::swap(a[i], a[i + 1]);
```

Comment: thanks I don't haved know this swap function thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck on it as well for sometime. This question has already been answered fine by VermillionAzure, but still pasting my solution. I ain't using the std::swap just because I like to do more by hand.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

//function to swap values
//need to pass by reference to sort the original values and not just these copies
void Swap (int *a, int *b)
{
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

void BubbleSort (std::vector<int> &array)
{
    std::cout<<"Elements in the array: "<<array.size()<<std::endl;

    //comparisons will be done n times
    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++)
    {
        //compare elemet to the next element, and swap if condition is true
        for(int j = 0; j < array.size() - 1; j++)
        {   
            if (array[j] > array[j+1])
                Swap(&array[j], &array[j+1]);
        }
    }
}

//function to print the array
void PrintArray (std::vector<int> array)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++)
        std::cout<<array[i]<<" ";
    std::cout<<std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout<<"Enter array to be sorted (-1 to end)\n";

    std::vector<int> array;
    int num = 0;
    while (num != -1)
    {
        std::cin>>num;
        if (num != -1)
            //add elements to the vector container
            array.push_back(num);
    }

    //sort the array
    BubbleSort(array);

    std::cout<<"Sorted array is as\n";
    PrintArray(array);

    return 0;
}
```